# Передача данных в POST через ссылку

Tags: php, post

Имею такой ответ сервера при регистрации пользователя,ловил через Fiddler:

```
fetch("http://url/reg.php?mod=goreg&refer=", {"credentials":"include","headers":{},
    "referrer":"url/reg.php","referrerPolicy":"no-referrer-when-downgrade",
    "body":"nick=Test&pass=Test&email=Test@test.ru&pol=m&storona=white&klas=fighert",
"method":"POST","mode":"cors"});
```

Вопрос,как можно все это собрать в строку вида

```
http://url/reg.php?mod=goreg&nick=Test&pass=Test&email=Test@test.ru&pol=m&storona=white&klas=fighert
```

Дабы можно было совершить регистрацию пользователя лишь по ссылке.

Вот так работает ссылка авторизации.

```
"http://url/enter.php?login="+name+"&pas="+password+""
```

Хотелось бы сделать возможность и регистрации таким же образом.
Надеюсь понятно выразил свою мысль ^^

Comment: например `$url = '...?payload='.urlencode($my_json_string);`

Comment: На сколько знаю, то передавать персональные данные в GET запросе - небезопасно и плохо

Comment: @manowartop, это делается для андроид клиента маленькой вап игрушки)
Там людей то будет не более пары десятков)

Comment: @rjhdby, я имел ввиду как-то это сделать в виде обычной ссылки как

`"http://url/enter.php?login="+name+"&pas="+password+""` ибо данные я туда передаю из андроид приложения

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что у вас не получается. Если у вас есть необходимые параметры, так и собирайте из него необходимую строку аналогично как с авторизацией. В чем затруднение то?

Comment: @rjhdby,спасибо,так и сделал)Не подумал сразу)